Can we compare the "quantity" of Z and Q by doing their quotient from R, and looking at the properties of the result?
It it well known that $$\operatorname{card}\mathbb{Z}=\operatorname{card}\mathbb{Q}$$
by doing a bijection. However, there seem to be some intuition that tells me that "somehow" $\mathbb{Q}$ should be larger than $\mathbb{Z}$.
For example, in the proof of the existence of non-measurable set, we use axiom of choice in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ and get a set with strange behavior. From here we construct the non-measurable set.
We use $\mathbb{Q}$ but not $\mathbb{Z}$. Now, does this show some important difference between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$? Can this - something like "the strangeness of the quotient set" - be used to describe the "amount" of the set?

I’m not sure if this really works but a concrete way to implement your idea is to observe that there exists a sequence of injective and invertible field homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so we can say that “Z” fits into “Q” which in turn fits into “R”.

Now I’m not sure if AC allows us to construct field homomorphisms going the other way. Definitely not injective and invertible ones

$\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ but $\mathbb Z$ is not

Remember that there's a big difference between comparing $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z$ as sets versus comparing them as subsets of $\Bbb R$ with its additional structures (ring operations, total ordering, Lebesgue measure). There are certainly many differences between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z$ in terms of how they interact with these structures; that doesn't contradict the two sets having the same cardinality, because these differences concern how the two sets are situated within $\Bbb R$ which is additional information.

This is in fact surprising , but it becomes better (or worse) : Even the set of the algebraic numbers is still countable ! It is not always easy to establish a concrete bijection and often we show the countability nonconstructive.
